# What perl script will scp directory with spaces in name?

Tags: perl, scp, whitespace

I"ve been trying for several hours to figure out how to get perl to `scp` a directory with a space in the name.  I'm currently getting the error

```
scp: ambiguous target
```

Here is the script that is not working:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Assuming you already have passwordless ssh setup from some account to root on HOST
# On HOST, setup test files and directories
# root@HOST$ mkdir /tmp/from/spaced\ mydir
# root@HOST$ touch /tmp/from/spaced\ mydir/t1
# root@HOST$ mkdir /tmp/to

my $HOST='localhost';
my $escaped_component_name = 'spaced mydir';

# try to form scp from-arg that will preserve the space
# in the directory name by escaping whitespace with backslash
$escaped_component_name =~ s/(\s)/\\$1/g;
my $scp_from = '/tmp/from/'.$escaped_component_name.'/*';
my $scp_to = '/tmp/to/'.$escaped_component_name;

system 'scp', '-vr', '--', 'root@'.$HOST.':'.$scp_from, 'root@'.$HOST.':'.$scp_to;
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I can't speak for perl since I don't use it, but when I used `scp` for the first time it took me ages to figure out what was wrong. I had to wrap the paths in quotes AND escape the special characters. Similar thing here, possibly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19196620/1742825

Comment: Depending on your SCP version, remote-to-remote transfers aren't supported. Can you confirm your SCP will do a remote-to-remote transfer?

Comment: Use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH), it will take care of quoting the arguments properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final script that worked for me.  Thanks to the input from @Ricky Beam and @arielCo.
          use File::Spec;

```
      my $escaped = $component_name;
      $escaped =~ s/(\s)/\\$1/g;

      # scp-from-path
      my $scp_from = File::Spec->catdir($REMOTE_MV_HOME, $escaped,'*');

      # scp-to-path
      my $scp_to = File::Spec->catdir($REMOTE_MV_HOME, $escaped, '\.');

      # use double-quotes on only the to-path because
      # of the double-shelling (local fork of 'sh' and then the remote execution 'sh')

      system 'scp', '-vr', '--', 'root@'.$HOST.':'.$scp_from, 'root@'.$HOST.':"'.$scp_to.'"' ;
```

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong?

Using `system`. That will fork a shell with the rest of your args as options. In other words, `sh` is eating the quoting.

Try:

```
system 'scp', '-vr', '--', '"root@'.$HOST.':'.$scp_from.'"', '"root@'.$HOST.':'.$scp_to.'"' ;`
```

Comment: From `perldoc -f system`, there's no intermediate shell unless there are shell metacharacters in the arguments. Try `perl -lwe 'system "pstree","-p",$$'` and you'll get `perl(21023)---pstree(21024)`.

Comment: @Ricky Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.  I finally got it working with the your help and arielCo.  This answer helped but didn't quite work.  With double-quotes on both the from-scp-argument and the to-scp-argument, scp failed with "No such file or directory" on the from-arg.  In contrast, I did need double-quotes for the to-arg but in a slightly different place than suggested in the answer.  The double-quotes only worked when applied to the path portion of the to-arg root@HOST:"path-portion" rather than "root@HOST:path-portion".

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure that `scp` supports remote-to-remote transfers? As far as I know, some versions do it with the `-3` switch.

Anyway, I keep this script handy for whenever I have trouble with arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $count;
for (@ARGV) {
  s/([\x00-\x1F\x7F])/'\x'.unpack('H*',$1)/ge;
  printf "%d: '%s'\n", ++$count, $_;
}
```

Let's try your code:

```
$ perl
my $HOST='localhost';
my $escaped_component_name = 'spaced mydir';

# try to form scp from-arg that will preserve the space
# in the directory name by escaping whitespace with backslash
$escaped_component_name =~ s/(\s)/\\$1/g;
my $scp_from = '/tmp/from/'.$escaped_component_name.'/*';
my $scp_to = '/tmp/to/'.$escaped_component_name;
system 'sandbox/args.pl', '-vr', '--', 'root@'.$HOST.':'.$scp_from, 'root@'.$HOST.':'.$scp_to;
# (Control-D)
1: '-vr'
2: '--'
3: 'root@localhost:/tmp/from/spaced\ mydir/*'
4: 'root@localhost:/tmp/to/spaced\ mydir'
```

Yup, the escaping is fine - my version of `scp` needs the backslashes in the destination path (but NOT in the local path); I guess it has to do with running `ssh` behind the scenes.

Let's try it with the real thing:

```
$ perl
$local_dir = "some dir/";
$remote_dir = "/tmp/some dir/";
$remote_dir  =~ s/(\s)/\\$1/g;
system 'scp', $local_dir."login.sql", 'user@host:'.$remote_dir;

# (Control-D)
login.sql            100% |********************************************|   434       00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Your answer helped but did not quite work.  It helped me realize I had to treat the scp-to-argument differently than the scp-from-argument.